# want to select all from a database where the query is a variable(discord username) using pandas and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, discord, discord.py

I am trying to set up a leaderboard in via a discord bot, where when the command !myscore is passed, the database row corresponding to that persons username is sent to the contexted channel, using pandas and sqlalchemy to make the table look nice, as well as trying to make the ouput a discord 'code block' (requres ``` at the beginning and end of the ctx.send message, which doesnt seem to want to be playing nice with pandas and adding strings to variable outputs).

```py
# send score for specific user
@bot.command(name='myscore', help='show score of specific')
async def scorecheck(ctx):
    user = str(ctx.message.author)
    print("recieved from " + user)
    userscore = cur.execute(
        'SELECT * FROM Leaderboard WHERE Username=?', (user, ))

    #query = "SELECT * from Leaderboards WHERE Username =?"
    #userscore = pd.read_sql_query(query, db, params={user})
    # (sa.text("SELECT * FROM Leaderboard WHERE Username=:user"), engine, params={"user": user})
    #userscore = pd.read_sql_query(query, db)
    print(ctx.message.author)
    await ctx.send(userscore)

    print('Score view successful')
```

the commented code is some  of the other stuff i have tried to make it work.

print messages are mostly there to see if the code is executing, as it wasnt outputting anything.

Current output to discord with all uncommented code is:
 `<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0F08F6A0>`

i am quite new to coding and am basically learning as i go, but havent had any luck getting this one sorted

below is the sql tables in sqlitestudio

[sql setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVVO5.png)

[current data in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc0XJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

What a column contains info about user's score? The code bellow is for column `score` in Leaderboard table. First, I fetch 1 row from table via `fetchrow`, 0 index element is user's score and userscore is an array of fetched columns with their contents.

````py
# send score for specific user
@bot.command(name='myscore', help='show score of specific')
async def scorecheck(ctx):
    user = str(ctx.message.author)
    print("recieved from " + user)
    userscore = cur.fetchrow(
        'SELECT score FROM Leaderboard WHERE Username=?', (user, ))

    if not userscore:
        await ctx.send("User {name} not in database :(".format(name=user))
        return


    await ctx.send("{name}'s score is {score}".format(
        name=user,
        score=userscore[0]
    ))

    print('Score view successful')
    ```
````

Comment: Using this code it prints the recieved from printline, but doesnt output anything in the discord channel

Comment: Show your Leaderboard's table structure

Comment: not 100% sure what you mean by that but have put up some pictures

Comment: userscore = cur.fetchrow('SELECT TotalPoints FROM Leaderboard WHERE Username=?', (user, ))